# Access Few Columns of a table from CrudRepository in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have an interface which is extending crud repository

```
public interface PersonRepo extends CrudRepository<Person, String> {

    @Query(value="select name from PERSON where addr=?1", nativeQuery = true)    
    List<Person> getPeronUsingAddress(String addr);

}
```

Person entity looks like this:

```
class Person {

private String name;
private String phoneNumber;
private String address;
//along with getters setters and all basic hibernate annotation to persist and retrieve
}
```

the person object is saved into the databse and at the time of retrieving the native query is working fine as hibernate executes correct query. But I am not able to get the return type.

1. If the return type is List of Person then I am getting **InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException**
2. If I create an interface and use the list of interface as return type like

   ```
    interface response {
       String getName();
    }

    List of Response interface getPeronUsingAddress(String addr);
   ```

   then I am getting proxy object in the service. I am not able to get the datas from proxy object.
3. Another approach I did is to use List of object as return type. But it is not possible to downcast to my Person Object.

How to do that.? Or is there any other solution by which  I can return selective columns from crud repository and get a Java object with those selected Columns.

Answer (score 1):

In order to fetch selected columns from an entity, you can do like below :

```
class Person {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String address;
    //along with getters setters and all basic hibernate annotation to persist and retrieve
}
```

Create a DTO or Java Object like below :

```
public class PersonDTO {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String address;

    public PersonDTO(Integer id, String name, String phoneNumber, String address) {
    // logic here
    }

    //If you want just want name and phone number.
    public PersonDTO(String name, String phoneNumber) {
    // logic here
    }

    // you can't create overridden constructors as all members are of same type and at runtime program won't be able to differentiate unless you provide some logic for it.

   // getters, setters, any other methods here...

}
```

Now below will be you Query but it's not native, if you want to keep native query then you will need to use ResultTransformer like [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/why-you-should-use-the-hibernate-resulttransformer-to-customize-result-set-mappings/)

```
@Query("select new your.package.PersonDTO(p.name, p.phoneNumber) from Person p where p.id = :id")
public PersonDTO getPersonById(Integer id);
```

Comment: Nice answer. More about projections could be found under https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.interfaces

Comment: Thank you @YiDoe ! And thanks for adding official docs.